# Springboot - filters automatically registered

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlet-filters

Because of some requirements, I need to have a javax.servlet.Filter being delivered as a bean (I create it and return from a method) - I autowire it later to component. My problem is, that I dont want to have it registered as Filter, what Springboot seems to do automatically. I found a solution with implementing WebApplicationInitializer, but it seems to be ignored. In other words, I want to specify filters I want to use by myself.

I am using spring-boot-starter-web

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cannot suggest anything without seeing the code.

Comment: Interesting conversation here that seems related/has some proposed solutions. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2173

Comment: I think I cannot place my code here. But, I am having a method with @Bean annotation, which returns object which is a Filter. As far as I see, spring is detecting such beans and automatically registers it as a filter. This is the behaviour I want to change. I want to have spring configured so I say "use this two filters" and it will use only filters I explicitly define.

Comment: @JohnHumphreys-w00te Thank you! After reading this issue I tried the solution with disabling the filter by defining FilterRegistrationBean, and it works as I expect. You saved a lot of my time :)

Comment: No problem at all :).  Happy it helped.  I'll throw an answer on based on that then so you can close it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per our comments above, you can solve this by the method described here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2173.

Define a filter registration bean and disable the filter within it.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registration() {
        DelegatingFilterProxy filter = filter(); // or inject it with a @Qualifier
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: I have created a class with the @Configuration annotation and defined the Bean therein. However the HiddenHttpMethodFilter is still filtering out my request body.